# Plotly: How to define an open marker without a line going through it using only a single trace?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I would like to plot a "lines+markers" plot with an circle-open marker without having the line go through it.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=x**2,
        mode='lines+markers',
        line=dict(color='green'),
        marker_size=16,
        marker_symbol='circle-open'
    )
)
fig.update_layout(
    plot_bgcolor='white'
)
fig.show()
```

This results in a line through the open marker.
Then I tried to add background-colored markers on top of a line - but then in the legend I only get the marker or the line, not both combined.

**Is there a way to get a legend with a marker and a line this way?**

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=x**2,
        mode='lines',
        line=dict(color='red'),
        showlegend=False,
        legendgroup='legend'
    )
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=x**2,
        mode='markers',
        marker_color='white',
        # line=dict(color='green'),
        marker_size=12,
        marker_symbol='circle',
        marker_line=dict(
            width=3,
            color='red'
        ),
    legendgroup='legend'
    )
)
fig.update_layout(
    plot_bgcolor='white',
)
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the correct combination of a few attributes should get you there:

1. `marker_symbol='circle'`
2. `marker_color = 'white'`
3. `marker = dict(line = dict(color='green', width = 2))`

#### Plot

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=x, y=x**2,
        mode='lines+markers',
        line=dict(color='green'),
        marker_size=16,
        marker_symbol='circle',
        name = 'no line through this',
        showlegend = True,
        
        marker_color = 'white',
        marker = dict(line = dict(color='green', width = 2))
    )
)
fig.update_layout(
    plot_bgcolor='white'
)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @DanaMiles Happy to help! If it was *exactly* what you were looking for, may I suggest that you perhaps would consider throwing in an upvote? In either case, thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: Oh, I thought the green tick is what counts.
Added the upvote now :)

Comment: @DanaMiles Thank you! An upvote gives +10 rep points and an accept gives +15 rep points. So both things count! But I actually value an upvote higher than the acceptance mark since this gives you +1 point on the badge that you give an answer to.

Comment: @DanaMiles If this means that you haven't given *any* upvotes to answers you have received, I would suggest that you take another look at them and award your upvotes where you see fit. Marking a suggestion as the accepted answer and not at the same time upvote it is a bit peculiar =)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I went over the older answers. Question: I now noticed that the hover-box has white as the bg color (bc white marker), and that the <extra>{x}</extra> element results in white text (white on white = hard to read). Can the color be changed to the line_color?